# ko.computed function is undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I've got two checkboxes representing names.  When either is clicked, the `selectedName()` observable is updated.  In addition, I've got two `ko.computed` functions that determine whether or not the checkboxes are checked.  Each checks to see if the `selectedName()` value matches a name.

The end result would be that the checkboxes act like similar to radio buttons.

Why would clicking a checkbox yield `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`?

I've also tried `checked: NameIsJohn()` and `checked: NameIsJohn() === 'True'` instead.  Also, I've tried binding `checkedValue: true` to the input elements.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: selectedName('John'), checked: NameIsJohn">John</input>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: selectedName('Jack'), checked: NameIsJack">Jack</input>

<script>

$(function() {
    var vm = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.selectedName = ko.observable();
        this.NameIsJohn = ko.computed( function() {
            return self.selectedName === 'John';
        });
        this.NameIsJack = ko.computed( function() {
            return self.selectedName === 'Jack';
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
)};

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3ek75nx/

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. Remove the NameIsJohn/NameIsJack bindings and the exact same error will remain. Weeding out this red herring will make it easier to focus on the "actual" issue(s).

Comment: Also, if the idea is that you can only select *one* option, then you should use a radio, not checkboxes.

Comment: @MattBurland Would using `ko.pureComputed()` make sense here, as it has a `write` option?  Also, I agree that using checkboxes to achieve what radio buttons do is not a common project requirement.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
data-bind="click: selectedName('John')"
```

You aren't binding `click` to the function `selectedName`. You are binding click the the *return value* of calling `selectedName('John')`. This, of course, is `undefined`, hence your error.

You need to provide a `function` for the `click` binding. You can do this by simply wrapping your call in a function:

```
data-bind="click: function() { selectedName('John') }"
```

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't easy for me to see.  I thought that clicking the checkbox would change the value of `selectedName()`, and that a dependency chain would be created between `selectedName()` and the `ko.computed` functions that I wrote, which would toggle the checkboxes.

Comment: Your click function will also need to return true to allow the click event to continue to process.
http://jsfiddle.net/h3ek75nx/12/

Comment: @RoyJ Thank you very much, your JSFiddle fixes the problem and completely answers my question.